# “An error has occurred. See the log file..” problem to install eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I installed eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS but can't open ecilpse. An error message pop up.

error message:

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file /home/sumon/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1582634683890.log
```

[error message screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1yIG.png)

log file:

```
sumon@sumon-Vostro-1450:~$ cat /home/sumon/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1582634683890.log
!SESSION Tue Feb 25 18:44:43 BDT 2020 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-02-25 18:44:43.927
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

[log file screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dibmh.png)

How to solve this problem? I like to mention that I installed another version of eclipse before and uninstall this.

Comment: You are trying to run a **very** old version of Eclipse (3.8 which is 8 years old) on a modern version of Java - this won't work. Use the current version of Eclipse (2019-12) or an older Java.